# Check if table exist using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello all decided to begin learning PDO. However i'm having trouble creating a function to check if a table exists in my db.

Each individual item has there own table in which the table name is ($id).

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = file_get_html('http://localhost:8888/CDOnline%20Online.html');

foreach($html->find('div.product-stamp-inner') as $content) {   

$detail['itemid'] = $content->find('a',0)->href;
$detail['itemid'] = substr($detail['itemid'], 40, 6);
if (strpos($detail['itemid'], "?") !== false) {
$detail['itemid'] = substr($detail['itemid'], 0, 5);
}
$id = $detail['itemid'];

tableExists($dbh, $id);
}

function tableExists($dbh, $id)
{
//check if table exists
}

$dbh = null;
?>
```

I've tried to scour the forums in search of an answer but came up empty handed. The only thing that got me close to my answer was:

```
function tableExists($dbh, $id)
{
$results = $dbh->query("SHOW TABLE LIKE `$id`");
if(count($results)>0){echo 'table exists';}
}
```

But that just says all tables exists, when half of the tables don't exist.

Edit:The table should exist if there is 1 or more rows.

Comment: By creating `n` copies of the same table you are just making your life more difficult. You need to have *one* table with an `item_id` column. Seriously.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using backtics around `$id`. Change it to single quotes. Like this:

```
"SHOW TABLES LIKE '$id'"
```

Further note that the statement `count($results)>0` will not work. You'll have to use `$results->rowCount()` instead.

---

Fxing both errors will give you the following function:

```
function tableExists($dbh, $id)
{
    $results = $dbh->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$id'");
    if(!$results) {
        die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), TRUE));
    }
    if($results->rowCount()>0){echo 'table exists';}
}
```

Comment: Note that counting the query result doesn't count the number of rows returned. You may want to use `$results->rowCount`.

Comment: Can you enable `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` for testing? Do you see errors?

Comment: Seems that there was an error with the query. Have added error checking code. Can you try again with that update and tell me what error message you get?

Comment: Here you go appreciate the help. Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LIKE '755823'' at line 1' in /bsx/bsx offline/grabber.php:52 Stack trace: #0 /bsx offline/grabber.php(52): PDO->query('SHOW TABLE LIKE...') #1 /bsx offline/grabber.php(45): tableExists(Object(PDO), '755823') #2 {main} thrown in /bsx offline/grabber.php on line 52

Comment: Shouldn't SHOW TABLE be SHOW TABLES

Comment: Haha looks like we have a winner ;) Thanks for all of your help hek2mgl!

Comment: You are welcome. Thank you too for helping me out with missing `s` .. Should have just copied the code from phpmyadmin.. :) ...

Comment: why nor make the second to the last line a 'elseif' as opposed to simple 'if'?

Comment: @BlackBeltScripting Yes, it could be used here as well.

Answer (score 2):

`SHOW TABLES...` is **MySQL** dialect and will fail under pretty much any other DB engine. This is certainly not the definitive answer to portable table detection.

The closest to portable you could get would be to check whether `SELECT * FROM $table` yields an error,
or similar methods discussed [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1227921/portable-sql-to-determine-if-a-table-exists-or-not)

If your need is simply to create a table if it does not exist, you can use:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table ($field, ...)
```

You might want to name your tables in ***lower case*** to work around [this bug](http://ledyardconsulting.blogspot.co.at/2011/03/mysql-error-1050-table-already-exists.html) if your DB is located on a Windows MySQL server, though.

Answer (score 1):

This is posted simply if anyone comes looking for this question. Even though its been answered a bit.

```
if ($con->query(
                   "SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $table . "'"
               )->rowCount() > 0
        or die("No table set")
   ){
```

With this I just push the else condition into or. And for my needs I only simply need die. Though you can set or to other things. Some might prefer the if / else if / else. Which is then to remove or and then supply if / else if / else.

Or if I was to redo the function:

```
function tableExists($dbh, $id){

    if ($dbh->query(
                   "SHOW TABLES LIKE '" . $id . "'"
               )->rowCount() > 0
        or die(print_r($dbh->errorInfo(), TRUE))
   ){
    echo 'table exists';
    }

}
```

Did not test the redo, though it should work the same as the code I have used before. Just in function.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the simplest way to do this. You pass this function an array with the pdo object you have already created.

```
$db['pdo']=new PDO('mysqlconnectiongoeshere');
$db['table']='tabletobechecked';

function is_table($db){
   $is_table=$db['pdo']->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '".$db['table']."'");
   return$is_table->rowCount();
}
```

This way if the table exists this function returns a '1' and if it doesn't exist this function returns a '0';

So you can use it like this:

```
if(is_table($db)){
  echo"The table".$db['table']." exists.";
}else{
  echo"The table".$db['table']." does not exist.";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private function doesTableExist($table)
{
    try {
        $this->db->query("DESC $table");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
         return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use good old row count. There must be a result if table exist.

```
$sql ="SELECT count(*) FROM [table name]";
$sql_result = $this->db_mssql->prepare($sql);
$sql_result->execute();
$sql_result->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$my_res = $sql_result->fetchAll();
if($my_res){
   echo 'table exists';
}
```